# MySQL type cast bug or expected behavior?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is an example of SQL query to a MySQL database table that contains a 32-length varchar string as UUID. As you can see WHERE clause doesn't contain the full string but MySQL returns results.

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid=9

```
id  uuid                                name
1   9c8f8632cbbac5b0708a9920f6fac755    John Smith
```

Is this an expected behavior and MySQL casts field's type and search condition?

Comment: I am guessing that `uuid` is stored as a string.

Comment: It is a string, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like MySQL does an implicit conversion from integer to string.

```
mysql> select 9 = '9asdasd';
+---------------+
| 9 = '9asdasd' |
+---------------+
| 1             |
+---------------+
1 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select 9 = '79asdasd';
+----------------+
| 9 = '79asdasd' |
+----------------+
| 0              |
+----------------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Apparently you need to make sure there are quotes to avoid this:

```
mysql> select '9' = '9asdasd';
+-----------------+
| '9' = '9asdasd' |
+-----------------+
| 0               |
+-----------------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior.  What is happening is that you are comparing a string to a an integer.  In this case, the *string* is converted to a number, based on the leading digits.

Because only the first letter is a digit, it gets converted to 9 -- so the equality works.